# linux: smart fsync()?

Tags: linux, sd-card, fsync

I'm recording audio and writing the same to a SD Card, the data rate is around 1.5 MB/s. I'm using a class 4 SD Card with ext4 file system.

After certain interval, kernel auto syncs the files. The downside of this is, my application buffers pile up waiting to be written to disk.

I think, if the kernel syncs frequently that what it is doing now, it may solve the issue.

I used `fsync()` in application to sync after certain intervals. But this does not solve the problem, because certain times kernel has synced just before the application called `fsync()`, so the fsync() called from application was a waste of time.

I need a syncing mechanism (say, `smart_fsync()` ), so that when application calls smart_fsync(), then the kernel will sync only if it has not synced in a while, else it will just return.

Since there is no function as `smart_fsync()`. what can be a possible workaround?

Comment: I don't really believe kernel will sync anything if you are not exceeding file buffer. By syncing manually (and quite often) you may reduce time of every sync, but in overall - time spent will remain almost the same. You also can use nonblocking i/o or writing thread, but it will be a bit tricky. Btw, 1.5Mb for class 4 is quite low. Disabling FS journal may help.

Answer (score 3):

The first question to ask is, *what exactly is the problem you're experiencing?* The kernel will flush dirty (unwritten cached) buffers periodically - this is because doing so tends to be faster than flushing synchronously (less latency hit for applications). The downside is that this means a larger latency hit if you reach the kernel's limit on dirty data (and potentially more data loss after an unclean shutdown).

If you want to ensure that the data hits disk ASAP, then you should simply open the file with the `O_SYNC` option. This will flush the data to disk immediately upon `write()`. Of course, this implies a significant performance penalty, but on the other hand you have complete control over when the data is flushed.

If you are experiencing drops in throughput while the syncing is going on, most likely you are attempting to write faster than the disk can support, and reaching the dirty page memory limit. Unfortunately, this would mean the hardware is simply not up to the write rate you are attempting to push at it - you'll need to write slower, or buffer the data up on faster media (or add more RAM!).

Note also that your 'smart fsync' is exactly what the kernel implements - it will flush pages when one of the following is true:
* There is too much dirty data in memory. Triggers asynchronously (without blocking writes) when the total amount of dirty data exceeds `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes`, or when the percentage of total memory exceeds  `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio`. Triggers synchronously (blocking your application's `write()` for an extended time) when the total amount of data exceeds `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes`, or the percentage of total memory exceeds  `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio`.
* Dirty data has been pending in memory for too long. The `pdflush` daemon checks for old dirty blocks every  `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` centiseconds (1/100 seconds), and will expire blocks if they have been in memory for longer than  `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs`.

It's possible that tuning these parameters might help a bit, but you're probably better off figuring out why the defaults aren't keeping up as is.